# How to allocate memory while using typedef?

Tags: c

I have a code segment which goes something like this

```
typedef struct node* node_t;

struct node{
int value;
node_t link;
};

......
......
......

//now I want to allocate memory somewhere else in the program.
node_t x;
x=(node_t) malloc(sizeof *x);
```

Could you please tell me if the above statement is proper? Eclipse shows this warning

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../tree.c:22:9:
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
```

Can someone explain in detail about situations like this? What is actually wrong with this. I would really appreciate if you could list all the possible ways in which I can allocate memory in this program? Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `malloc` you will need to include `<stdlib.h>`. Additionally, allocate memory like

```
node_t x = malloc(sizeof node_t);
```

You must not assign memory to stack-variables, but only to pointers. And never cast back to the allocated type, as `malloc` returns `void*` and this need not be casted explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You need an

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

before you use `malloc`. You apparently declared the function wrong in your source. Never declare C standard library functions. Just include the headers that declare them.

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please tell me if the above statement is proper?

No, it isn't: you're casting the return value of `malloc()` and you're missing the `<stdlib.h>` header.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the warning because you don't have a declaration for `malloc` in scope; you need to include the `stdlib.h` header file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

You should also drop the cast.  It isn't necessary, and under other compilers will suppress a diagnostic that you're trying to assign an `int` value to a pointer type.

*Please* do not hide pointers behind typedefs.  It's almost always a bad idea.